# There is a compact subset of intersection some subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous function. Assume that $G$ and $U$ are full Lebesgue set. Let $\mu$ be a Borel regular probability measure and for any $\epsilon>0$ let $Y:=\{f^{n}(x) \text{ that is } \epsilon-\text{approch the support } \mu \}$ be a subset of $X$ with $Leb(Y)>0$ . Can we find a compact set $D$ such that
$$D\subset U \cap G \cap Y?$$

Attempt:  the support of $\mu$ is the largest closed set $C$ such that  for all open sets $U$ with $Q\cap C \neq \phi$, we have $\mu(Q)>0$. If $Y \cap C \neq \emptyset$, then it is easy to find such a compact set..